# Cutting strings in C language using string.h library

Tags: c, string.h

To solve this problem I need to use string.h library. I need to read napis1 and napis2 and store them in variables. Then I need to find first occurence of napis2[0] in napis1 and the last occurence of napis2[0] in napis2. After that, I want to cut napis1 until the first occurence of napis2[0] not including napis2[0] and also cut napis2 between the first char and the last occurence of napis2[0] including. How to do this, is it possible using pointers?

```
char napis1[128];
char napis2[64];
scanf(" %63[ -~]s", &napis1);
scanf(" %63[ -~]s", &napis2);
char znak = napis2[0];
char *ptr1 = NULL;
char *ptr2 = NULL;
ptr1 = strchr(napis1, znak);
ptr2 = strrchr(napis2, znak);
```

Comment: For the `n`:th time: the `%[]` conversion specifier is its own thing, it is *not* a modifier for `%s`.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output. What have you tried to do the cutting?